# How to add a new test item in an already existing VC++ project?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++

According to [this MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-testing-existing-cpp-applications-with-test-explorer#sameProject), I should be able to add a new test item by:

> 2. Add a C++ Unit Test file:
>
>    - In Solution Explorer, in the shortcut menu of the project, choose **Add, New Item**, and then choose **C++ Unit Test**.

But such an item doesn't exist.  I'm using VS2015 U3.  Where is this Unit Test item the documentation is describing?  How to I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I couldn't figure out how to get “**C++ Unit Test**” to appear as an option, but I found out it isn't necessary to run unit tests from within an existing native C++ project.

1. Add a plain, blank “**C++ File (.cpp)**” from the “*Add New Item*” window.
2. Add the unit testing code manually; if you're not sure where to start, you can begin with the basic boilerplate code that you'd get from the C++ Unit Test new item. Mine looked like this:

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "CppUnitTest.h"

   using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

   namespace MyCppTestFile
   {       
       TEST_CLASS(MyCPPTestClass)
       {
       public:

           TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
           {
               // TODO: Your test code here
           }

       };
   }
   ```
3. Open the **Test Explorer** window (**Test** › **Windows** › **Test Explorer**) and click **Run All**. The test runner will be sure your build is    up-to-date, and if you added `$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include` and `$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib` to your configuration like the MSDN documentation instructed, it should automagically discover any and all unit test source code you've added to your project.

Comment: Yeah, I've done this already.  I was wondering if there was another way.